# My django-server doesn't find my CSRF token

Tags: reactjs, django, http, post

CORS related:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://127.0.0.1:8000', 
                        'http://127.0.0.1:8001',
                        'http://localhost:3000']


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False

CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "X-CSRFToken"

CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = [
    'Content-Type', 'X-CSRFToken'
]
```

My react-code:

```
const fetchToken = async () => {
          try {
            const getTokenApiUrl = UrlApi + `/payment/`;
            const response = await fetch(getTokenApiUrl);
            const jsonData = await response.json();
            setCsrfToken(jsonData.token)
            
            
            
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Feil ved henting av data:', error.message);
          }
        };

Cookies.set('X-CSRFToken', csrfToken, { expires: 7});

const response = await fetch(sendPayementUrl, {
            method: 'POST', // Angi metoden til POST
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'X-CSRFToken' : Cookies.get('X-CSRFToken'),

              
            },
```

My views.py code:

```
@csrf_protect
def initializePayment(request):
    

    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = {
        'token' : None
        }
        data['token'] = get_token(request)
        
        print(data)
        return JsonResponse(data, status=200)
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        
        received_token = request.headers.get('X-CSRFToken')  # Hent token fra headeren
        print(received_token)
        
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Fikk ikke hentet data fra request")
        else:
            print("Data:", data)



        print("Sukess")
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Dine data ble behandlet riktig.'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Noe gikk galt'})
```

The POST-request is accepted by the CORS, but django tells me that "Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)". I can see by my eyes, that the token is send to the frontend when it reloads, placed in the cookies-storage by my code in react and then sent back to django when I post it. Why aren't django satisfied with all this?